# Is there anybody can show me how the voltage distribution of this MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, simulation

I have a problem to solve.
Below is the my question
[image]

I want to see how the voltage distribution of this mosfet.

Like this(below)
[image]

at this case, it's e-Density. (It's my school's data, I can't run this program.)
But I want to see Voltage all region.
Is there anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

In Sentaurus (T-Cad) you should change *electron density* to *potential*.

However, assuming that you have a quasi-static field you can compute the Potential from Maxwell's first law:

$$ \nabla \cdot \vec{D} = \rho $$.

Knowing that

$$\vec{E} = - \nabla V$$

using 
$$ \vec{D} = \epsilon \cdot \vec{E}$$

and

$$\nabla \cdot \nabla = \Delta$$

you will get the well known Laplace equation 
$$ \Delta V = - \frac{\rho}{\epsilon} $$

In your case the electron densitiy is equal the charge denistiy times e (elementary charge). So the result is:
$$ \Delta V = - \frac{e\cdot n}{\epsilon} $$